# Tool to diagonalize large matrices

Tags: matlab, r, matrix, octave, eigenvalue

I want to compute a diffusion kernel, which involves taking exp(b*A) where A is a large matrix. In order to play with values of b, I'd like to diagonalize A (so that exp(A) runs quickly).

My matrix is about 25k x 25k, but is very sparse - only about 60k values are non-zero. Matlab's "eigs" function runs of out memory, as does octave's "eig" and R's "eigen." Is there a tool to find the decomposition of large, sparse matrices?

Dunno if this is relevant, but A is an adjacency matrix, so it's symmetric, and it is full rank.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried SVD, `svds` for sparse matrix in matlab.

EDIT: one more thing, don't do full rank SVD since the dimension is big, use a small rank, say 500, so that your solution fits in the memory. This cuts the small eigenvalues and their vectors out. Thus it does not hurt your accuracy much.

Comment: @ A = USV'.  S is a square matrix with eigenvaules on the its diagonal.

Comment: +1 

@duffymo: See wikipedia on relationship between svd and eigenvalue decomposition. In any case the OP was asking for diagonalization of A which svd does.

Comment: I tried doing this on mine and it said "maximum variable size exceeded." My computer isn't exactly top-of-the-line though, so it could be a problem there instead of with matlab.

Comment: @ Xodarap. Matlab's svds is not the best there. You could also try http://tedlab.mit.edu/~dr/SVDLIBC/. When you start, you first make sure SVD does your job by trying small matrices.

Comment: @Yin - this is an excellent idea, but do you know how much information is lost? I feel like since this is an adjacency matrix and the rows are really quite independent of each other, finding only 10% of the eigenvalues (or whatever) will lose 90% of the info.

Comment: @Xodarap. Very little. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Matrix_approximation

You can also do some experiments on small matrices to see the difference between approximation and the exact value.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the [following property](http://cnx.org/content/m10679/latest/):
exp(A*t) = L^(-1) {(sI-A)^(-1)}
where L^(-1) the inverse Laplace transform? - provided that you can invert (sI-A)

Comment: I think inverse laplace runs in O(n^4), which is very slow. It's also prone to errors. See http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/19ways+.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a 64 bit machine and octave compiled with 64 bit support, you might be able to get around this problem.

Also, I don't know what platform you are running all of this on, but in UNIX based systems you can use `ulimit` to increase the maximum allowed stack size for user processes.

For example, you can run

```
ulimit -u unlimited
```

and this will ensure that there are no memory limits etc on your processes. This is not a good idea in general, since you have have runaway processes that will completely bog down your machine.  Try instead

```
ulimit -s [stacksize]
```

to increase the stack size limit.

Answer (score 0):

Octave has splu which does lu decomposition for sparse matrices. I am not sure whether it can handle 25k x 25k but worth a shot.

Alternatively if your matrix is structured like so: A = [B zeros;zeros C] then you can diagonalize B and C separately and put them together into one matrix. I am guessing you can do something similar for eig.

Comment: Stupid question, but once I do have lu, how do I use this? I realize that det(A) = det(L)*det(U), so there must be some relationship between their diagonalizations, but I'm not smart enough to see it.

Answer (score 0):

In R you could check [igraph package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/) and function `arpack` which is interface to [ARPACK library](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/).